# Как передать значение переменной в текстовый файл?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Есть определенный текстовый файл, например, test и есть переменная `var_test`.

Как передать значение переменной в текстовый файл?

С `input` знаю, что нужно `%text:name%`. Файл никуда не надо сохранять, далее эти переменные выводятся вместе с определенным кодом.

Comment: js же не может работать с файловой системой. или у вас nodejs?

Comment: Да, стоит nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала устанавливаем `fs` пакет:

```
npm i fs
```

Далее можно написать примерно так:

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('test.txt', var_test);
```

Для обработки ошибок передаём функцию доп параметром:

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('test.txt', var_test, function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);      
});
```

Можно так же выбирать кодировку файлов. Вызов будет тогда вида:

```
fs.writeFile(filename, data, [кодировка], [callback])
```

Варианты кодировок: 'ascii', 'utf8', and 'base64'. По умолчанию 'utf8'.

Comment: `npm i fs` вы серьёзно?

Comment: @nörbörnën, 800К человек в неделю считает так же как он :(

Comment: @nörbörnën, дубликат чего?

Answer (score 2):

В [API File system](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/fs.html) Node.js есть два подхода к записи в файл, основанные [на блокирующих и неблокирующих вызовах](https://nodejs.org/ru/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/).

#### Синхронная запись

> [fs.writeFileSync(file, data[, options])](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('foo.txt', `hello world ${Date.now()}`);
```

Это - блокирующая операция. Выполнение js кода в Node.js приостановлено до тех пор, пока не завершится работа операции записи.

#### Асинхронная запись

> [fs.writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

После выполнения записи будет вызван `callback`. Метод fs.writeFile является неблокирующим, поэтому исполнение другого кода будет продолжаться.

```
fs.writeFile('foo.txt', `hello world ${Date.now()}`, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log('The file was saved!');
});
```

> [fsPromises.writeFile(file, data[, options])](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options)

То же, что и предыдущее, но с promise (async / await).

```
const fs = require('fs');
(async () => {
  try {
    await fs.promises.writeFile('foo.txt', `hello world ${Date.now()}`);
    console.log('The file was saved!');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

> [fs.createWriteStream(path[, options])](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options)

Поток предназначенный для записи данных. Очень удобная штука.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const stream = fs.createWriteStream('foo.txt');
stream.once('open', () => {
  stream.write('hello world');
  stream.write(`${Date.now()}`);
  stream.end();
});
```

Comment: А в последнем примере всё хорошо? Это же асинхронная запись - даже последовательное размещение двух записей у меня вызывает некоторые сомнения, а уж закрытие - так вообще.